# html2js equivalent for Visual Studio to compile AngularJS templates

Tags: angularjs, visual-studio, gruntjs

Is there a Visual Studio equivalent of html2js with grunt to compile Angular template files, as used, for example, in this [angular app](https://github.com/angular-app/angular-app)?

I'm asking this question because it took me a while to find the excellent solution I eventually came across, which I've put in my answer below. I hope posting it here will make it easier to find on Google.

I've previously used grunt with html2js to compile Angular templates. On my current project we have to use Visual Studio. I'm using the AngularJS SPA Template, available [here](https://visualstudiogallery.msdn.microsoft.com/5af151b2-9ed2-4809-bfe8-27566bfe7d83).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After some searching, I found this [excellent blog post](http://code.dortik.net/bundling-angularjs-html-pages-with-asp-net/) and related [github project](https://github.com/omeganet/AngularJS-HTML-Bundling), which solved the problem brilliantly.  My thanks to Boyan Mihaylov, the author.